# Redirect URL with query string htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to redirect /path/?start=10 to https://www.example.com/new-path/

How can I do this for every URL needed in my .htaccess?

I have tried:

`redirectMatch 301 ^/path/?start=10 https://www.example.com/new-path/`

`RewriteRule ^/path/?start=10$ https://www.example.com/new-path/`

`Redirect 301 /path/?start=10 https://www.example.com/new-path/`

but none of these work.

Answer (score 2):

You can not **RedirectMatch** or **Redirect** queryString , you need to use **RewriteRule** for this purpose:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /path/\?start=10
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/new-path? [L,R]
```

An empty question mark at the end of the destination url is important to discard old querystring from the new url. If this is omitted ,mod rewrite will append querystring to the target url and your url will look something like **http://example.com/new-path?test=10** .

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod alias :

```
Redirect 301 /path/?start=10 /new-path/
```

Or use mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^/path/?start=10$ /new-path/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I need it to redirect to https at the same time.